# how to wire a light fixture to a plug?

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting

I have a light fixture that I want to wire to a plug-in wiring setup. The fixture has three white wires and three black wires, it also has a separate, bare ground wire. My plug style wiring is a normal 2x15A 300v plug. One side has a ribbed edge and the other has a smooth edge. 
The fixture is a three bulb setup, thus, the three wire connection. I am just unsure how to safely wire this to a plug in wiring arrangement.
Thank you.

Comment: You have not mentioned a switch.  How do you plan to turn the light on and off?

Comment: If only there were such as a standard plug.  Even if we knew what part of the world you are in we still might have to guess.  Photos of the lamp and plug would help greatly.

Comment: Yes, where the heck do the use 300V mains?

Comment: @Grant, is there an instance where ribbed to the white wires and smooth to the black isn't the right way to wire this?  Regardless of mains voltage?

Comment: Related, if not outright duplicate: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/29496/which-side-of-a-two-wire-cable-should-be-used-for-hot

Comment: I guess 300V is (a typo or) the insulation rating on the plug and 2x15A means two-pin plug (no earth) rated at 15A. Given the black/white wire insulation that makes it likely a typical US 120V(nominal) 15A circuit.

Comment: Need more detail. Photos trump detail if you can post them.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you are repairing or replacing the light fixtures plug? And if so you would like to know how the wires are connected? The lamp cord as you noticed, has a hot side (which is marked with 'ribs' on the plastic insulation. The other smooth side is the neutral. The repair plug you have is a 2 prong (male) type plug? Which means there is no ground for the fixture. The white wires at the fixture are twisted together and so are the 3 black wires. In order to connect the plug you must connect a white length of wire (and the same for the black) to the wires at the fixture. Twist them tight and secure with a wire nut. You should now have two wires connected to the fixture. ******Please read****:  This answer is assuming a lot from your question. If my second guessing is correct please say so in the comments section below and I will continue responding with an answer.*******